# Swift 4 selectRow for pickerView is not working in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am using `UIPickerView` and it's being triggered by pushing a button like so:

```
@IBAction func communityButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //Set the picker view delegate to self
    pickerView.delegate = self

    //Set the picker view data source to self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    //Define the tool bar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()

    //Set tool bar style
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    //Set tool bar translucent to true
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true

    //Resizes and moves the tool bar view so it just encloses its subviews.
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    //Define done button for tool bar
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Dashboard.donePicker))

    //Define space inbetween the buttons for tool bar
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    //Define cancel button for tool bar
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Dashboard.cancelPicker))

    //Assign tool bar buttons to tool bar
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)

    //Set the tool bar to be interactive
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    //Add the tool bar to the picker view
    pickTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    //Add picker view to view
    view.addSubview(pickTextField)

    //Assign the picker view to picker text field
    pickTextField.inputView = pickerView

    //Set picker text field as first responder
    pickTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Now I am trying to set a selected row in the `viewDidAppear` but it's not setting the selected row.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //Call method to get the user bundle settings
    registerSettingsBundle()

    //Apply the users bundle settings
    updateDisplayFromDefaults()

    //Clear the picker options
    pickOption = [String]()

    //For each community in the app delegate community array
    for item in (appDelegate.communityDescriptionArray?["kCommunityDescriptions"] as! [AnyObject])
    {
        //Add it to the picker options
        pickOption?.append(item as! String)
    }

    self.selectedIndex = (appDelegate.communityDescriptionArray?["kCommunityDescriptions"]!.index(of: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "community")!))!

    self.pickerView.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

I did noticed that my `viewDidAppear` is loaded first then `numberOfRowsInComponent`, then `titleForRow`, is that why the selected row is not taking?

Comment: I think you should use `self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` after selectRow

Comment: Nope that did not work.

Comment: perform reload before select the row. And setup your picker view in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear you are initialising  pickerview in button action event. in action event just keep become first responder